# WinForms ListBox does not fill whole space when Dock property is set fo Fill

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When adding a `ListBox` to a `SplitterPanel` and set its `Dock` property to `Fill`, it seems that the `ListBox` does not take all the available space. Please take a look at the following example. You might notice the small gap at the bottom of the `ListBox`:

[image: ListBox Dock]

This is the layout of the `Form`:

[image: Form Layout]

Both, the `ListBox` on the left and the `TextBox` on the right, have their `Dock` property set to `Fill`. The `TextBox` behaves as expected, but for the `ListBox` there is always a small gap.

Is this a bug? Do you have a workaround?

P.S.: Tested on Windows 10 x64, Version 1703 with .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: Works fine for me. Clearly something else is adding padding or something to that panel. Can you show the relevant designer code?

Comment: [`ListBox.IntegralHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.integralheight(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Sinatr Setting the `ListBox`s `IntegralHeight` property to `False` resolved my problem. This is the solution. Thank you very much! If you add your comment as an answer to my question, I can choose it as the right answer.